# 'Account' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Tags: django, sitemap

When attempting to access my sitemap.xml, I'm receiving this error:

```
'Account' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url' on line 112.

109.    def get_absolute_url(self):
110.        if self.group is None:
111.            return reverse('wiki_article', args=(self.title,))
112.        return self.group.get_absolute_url() + 'wiki/' + self.title
```

I can't find this 'Account' object in the traceback. Am I failing to import something here? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 5):

You have to define that method.

---

**get_absolute_url**

*Model.get_absolute_url()*

Define a get_absolute_url() method to tell Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object. To callers, this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

For example:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/people/%i/" % self.id
```

While this code is correct and simple, it may not be the most portable way to write this kind of method. The reverse() function is usually the best approach.

For example:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('people.views.details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, or this wiki app, but it simply sounds like your `Account` model doesn't have a `get_absolute_url` method.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.location

> If location isn't provided, the
>   framework will call the
>   get_absolute_url() method on each
>   object as returned by items().

Are you using this app? http://code.google.com/p/django-wikiapp/source/browse/trunk/wiki/models.py?r=161 (I just searched your traceback to find it)

`Group` is a generic foreign key so it can point to any of your models, which means every model it points to must have a `get_absolute_url` defined.

**Update:**

If you don't have an `Account` model, I'd suggest searching for it in `django.contrib.contenttypes.ContentType` because apparently an article is referencing it..

```
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   ContentType.objects.filter(model__icontains="account")
```

Do you get any results?

**Update:**

So you've found an `'account'` `ContentType`.

Now you can get the class via `contenttype.model_class()` and thus find it to implement `get_absolute_url()` there **or** since it sounds like you're not actually using this class, you can find which `Article`'s are pointing to this mysterious `account` ContentType by querying `Article` by `ContentType`.

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model__icontains='account')
articles_pointing_to_account = Article.objects.filter(content_type__pk=content_type.pk)

# Now it's your choice what to do with these articles. 
# I'd be curious what they are and how they managed to pull off this stunt
# before removing their generic relation to Account
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using that app, but I have no 'Account' model.

Comment: Perplexing. Try querying ContentType for `Account` (post updated), perhaps it existed at some point or you're using another app that has this model??

Comment: I recieved: [<ContentType: account>]. That is all.

Comment: Bam! There's your problem. Updating post